# Swift 2 iOS9 text case check

Tags: swift2, ios9

I'm trying to find a solution for the following example.  I have created a user registration page and I check that the password reset question does not match the actual password (works okay), but what I want to do is convert the inputted password and password reset question to say lower case and check there is no match.  I would prefer to do this on the fly rather that put the password into a var.

The reason for doing this is to ensure that the password reset question is not the same as the actual password regardless capitalisation of specific chars.

```
    if (passWord.text) == (resetQuestion.text) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "PASSWORD SECURITY ISSUE", message:
            "password reset question must not match actual password!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }


    if String.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(passWord.text) == String.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(resetQuestion.text) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "PASSWORD SECURITY ISSUE", message: 
            "password reset question must not match actual password!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }
```

Any pointers or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a caseInsensitiveCompare method that you could try. Something like

```
if passWord.text.caseInsensitiveCompare(resetQuestion.text) == .OrderedSame {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "PASSWORD SECURITY ISSUE", message:
        "password reset question must not match actual password!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luke,  that worked perfectly.  I just had to add ! after passWord.text and resetQuestion.text.

Comment: String is not a class in Swift. lowercaseString and uppercaseString are instance properties, so "Ab".uppercaseString == "AB is true etc.

Comment: @dacrozz Thats okay glad it worked :). I see you had to unwrap the values.